# Cookie help in js?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Okay so I have made 2 functions for cookie saving:

Setting Cookies:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {
    document.cookie.concat(" " + cname + "=" + cvalue + ";");
    console.log("Saved cookie!");
}
```

Loading cookies:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        if (document.cookie.indexOf(cname) > 0) {
            return document.cookie.substring(cname, (indexOf(";", indexOf(cname)) - 1));
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The reset cookies:

```
function resetCookies() {
        document.cookie = "";
}
```

However, my problem is that once you load everything; all the values are 0.

Here is some example of the code I was using. (since I tried to load about 60 cookies, it would just make it longer to read.)

```
function save() {
 clearCookies();
 setCookie("asdfghjklX", 10)
 setCookie("hiX", 20)
}
```

Then loading: (*I DID DEFINE THE VARIABLES IN THE SCRIPT IM HAVING PROBLEMS WITH BY THE WAY*)

```
function load() {
 hi = getCookie("hiX");
 asdfghjkl = getCookie("asdfghjklX", 20)
}
```

If someone could help that would be great, thanks!

Comment: Should cookies just come from the server?

Comment: @EdHeal what do you mean by that?

Comment: I thought that cookies only have meaning to the web server. So probably a bad idea for the client to cook them up

Comment: So you're saying that it wouldn't work if I made this on a .html document. Whereas, if I put this on a public server it would save the cookie?

Comment: Is it that you want to store data just client side?  Will the server never have to see those cookies?  If so, then you'd be much better off using HTML 5 local storage, see http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html (supported by all recent browsers)

Comment: Yeah, I just want the data client side, but also on a web server, since I'm publishing the game to a site.

Answer (score 0):

It will work but it's not a good idea to send cookies to server with every request that are useless (to server). Instead use localStorage.

But if you wan't to set/remove cookies from client you can use a **[library](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie)** from mozilla (MDN).

you can set a cookie like this:

```
docCookies.setItem(name, value[, end[, path[, domain[, secure]]]])
```

remove a cookie:

```
docCookies.removeItem(name[, path[, domain]])
```

get value:

```
docCookies.getItem(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code mostly works, your issues are that

A) you're saving the cookies with a whitespace in front ie. `" hiX=20"`

B) Use the split array `ca` instead and see if your cookie is set.

```
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    if (ca[i].indexOf(cname) > 0) {
        return ca[i];
    }
}
```

That being said, there are plenty of libraries out in the wild that makes handling of cookies easy as sunday mornings, such as https://github.com/ScottHamper/Cookies.